# Accessing database table and verifying content of fields

Tags: pentaho

I am trying to fetch a field in my Db table using below logic.

Table has 3 fields viz..

ID

REGION

LOC_ID

ID=123

REGION= Texas_1 (can be Texas_2 or Texas_3)

LOC_ID=101

I have an input file which gives me ID and I need to hard code the "REGION" values.

Step 1: check if ID is present.

Step 2: If it is present, individually check whether value of "REGION" is present.(viz. check for Texas_1 if present extract LOC_ID else check for Texas_2 ..)

Step 3: extract LOC_ID

I tried database join to perform the Step 1. But, I am not able to check "REGION" and not to able to implement "if-else" conditions that is required on accessing database table. I tried "

Please help

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful. Also, since all your questions miss it, you should have a read to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a basic SQL question, not a Pentaho one. Still:

```
select 
loc_id,
region
from mySchema.myDBtable
where id = 123 
and region in ('Texas_1','Texas_2','Texas_3')
```

This will return both region and loc_id for all rows that have the specified id and are in the 3 Texas regions. You can remove region from immediately after the select to return just loc_id. 
Obviously, you should replace `mySchema.myDBtable` with your schema and table names.

The generic structure of a SQL query is

```
SELECT
 ITEM0 [, Item1, Item2, Item3, sum(Item3) -- optional extras + aggregate]
FROM  SCHEMA.TABLE
 WHERE ROWCONDITION [ and ROWCONDITION2 and ROWCONDITION3]
--GROUP BY [GROUPCOLUMN] (Commented, only use for aggregates)
ORDER BY ORDERCOLUMN
```